Allowed statements inside a `SubroutineDefintion` for openqasm
I am currently building a semantic analyser for the openqasm3 specificcation. While referring to the openqasm specification I could only find that QubitDeclarations and ArrayType classical declarations are not allowed in the body of the SubroutineDefinition.
Are there any other "black-listed" ops inside the body? Currently I have the following set -
FUNCTION_BLACKLIST_STMTS = {
    QubitDeclaration, 
    ClassicalDeclaration, # with ArrayType as the type
    QuantumGateDefinition,
    SubroutineDefinition,
}

I figured that probably new functions or gates can't be defined in the body of a function.
Any views on this will be helpful. Thanks!
